# Cube root of a negative number

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to find the cube root of a negative number but I get a NaN. Any help?

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(-8, 1.0 / 3.0));
```

Comment: Did you check [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))? It explicitly lists the cases where the result will be NaN.

Comment: You can also use this `System.out.println(Math.cbrt(-8.0));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Java documentation for `Math.pow` states:

> If the first argument is finite and less than zero [...] [and] if the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the result is NaN.

You could use `Math.cbrt` to get the cube root:

```
double result = Math.cbrt(-8.0);
```

Comment: +1 for including solution; it's too hard to do all this on my phone--link was all I could muster.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that mathematically, there are 3 cube-roots. Assuming you want the root that is real, you should do this:

```
x = 8;  //  Your value

if (x > 0)
    System.out.println(Math.pow(x, 1.0 / 3.0));
else
    System.out.println(-Math.pow(-x, 1.0 / 3.0));
```

**EDIT :** As the other answers mention, there is `Math.cbrt(x)`. (which I didn't know existed)

The reason why `pow` returns `NaN` with a negative base and non-integral power is that powering is usually done by angle-magnitude in the complex plane.

- For positive real numbers, the angle is zero, so the answer will still be positive and real.
- For negative real numbers, the angle is 180 degrees, which (after multiplying by a non-integral power) will always produce a complex number - hence a `NaN`.

Comment: Did you check that the second case will not return NaN?

Comment: No I didn't. Is there a case that will make the second case go `NaN` without actually putting in `NaN` or infinity?

Comment: Indeed. The case we're discussing ;)

Comment: See the other answers; it's why I commented the link originally. Plus it's the exact code that returns NaN, just with a variable and a unary negative in front of it.

Comment: So you're telling me that `Math.pow(8, 1.0 / 3.0)` returns `NaN`?

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding, can you clarify exactly what is the second case? The way I'm seeing it is: `x = -8`, then it goes into the `else` and calls `Math.pow(8, 1.0 / 3.0)`.

Comment: Oh, never mind, misread; duh. The perils of tiny screens and type--sorry.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cbrt(double)

```
System.out.println(Math.cbrt(-8));
```

Comment: I think you got beat by both a comment and a previous answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html:

> **If the first argument is finite and less than zero**
>
> - if the second
>     argument is a finite even integer, the result is equal to the result
>     of raising the absolute value of the first argument to the power of
>     the second argument
> - if the second argument is a finite odd integer,
>     the result is equal to the negative of the result of raising the
>     absolute value of the first argument to the power of the second
>     argument
> - **if the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the
>     result is NaN.**