# Calculating pow() of negative number to non-integral exponent

Tags: .net, math

Ok, so I've gathered from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290804/cube-root-of-a-negative-number) that when you take pow() using a negative number with a non-integral exponent, the result is NaN.

So my question is: Is there some alternative method I can use to get an answer? I just want to be able to do things like this:

```
MyPowFunction(-3125, 0.2);
```

and have the result be (correctly) -5.

Any thoughts?

---

As an addendum, it is *possible* to do this (somehow). Google has it figured out: https://www.google.com/search?q=%28-3125%29%5E0.2&oq=%28-3125%29%5E0.2

---

One more note: I'm not interested in a double result--I'm perfectly fine with the result being complex.

Comment: Nice. And what should be `MyPowFunction(-1, 0.1)`?

Comment: Ideally, `0.951056516 + 0.309016994 i`

Comment: (I didn't say I wanted a double--I want to get pointed in the right direction for a good way to calculate the mathematically correct answer)

Comment: Are you aware of `Complex.Pow`?

Comment: @interjay, nope. If it works, post it as an answer!

Comment: How is `(-3125)^0.2 = -5` correct? It should be `4.04... + 2.93... i` or `5 exp(36° i)`. Google is wrong about this, don't trust its calculator.

Comment: @Anthales, (-5)^5 = -3125. The question I posted was the inverse. Now there may be some non-real answers as well, but there is at least 1 real answer

Comment: -5 ^ 5 = -3125 on my calculator. What are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a is **positive** and b is (complex) arbitrary, then one may define a^b as exp(b log a). This extends directly the case where b is a rational number.

Now, if a is complex (but nonzero), one may define a^b by **analogy** (proper term is "analytic continuation") as exp(b Log a), where Log is **one possible inverse** of exp.

For instance, one possible Log function (there are infintely many, differing by multiples of 2 i pi) is

```
Log z = log |z| + i(arg z + 2k pi), k as you wish
```

Check that for any k, this gives an inverse to exp (I skip the details about the domain of definition: just pretend there is only one z, and we want to find Log z such that exp(Log z) = z).

The way you choose k will thus influence the answer. If b is irrational, then

```
"a^b" = exp(b Log a) = exp(ib arg a) * exp(2i k pi * b) * |a|
```

and since k can be arbitrary, exp(2i k pi * b) can be arbitrary close to whatever number you want on the unit circle (unit circle = numbers with unit modulus), there are infinitely many values of "a^b" possible.

If b is rational (like 0.2 = 1/5 in your example), then you'll get 5 different candidates for a^0.2 (one of which is real).

Comment: Wonderful explanation. It is clear that I have a lot to learn, and this answer seeks to "explain" rather than to just "tell"

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that `-5` is *not* "the mathematically correct answer", for the following reasons:

- 0.2 is not exactly 1/5.  You're actually asking for -3125 to the 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125th power, which has a very large family of solutions.
- The usual mathematical convention is to pick the solution of x^y that you get from evaluating exp(y*log(x)), where log(x) is taken to have a branch cut on the negative real axis.  -3125 lies on the branch cut, so you have to decide which side it's on.  Convention is to put it on the positive side.
- Even assuming that 0.2 were representable in floating-point, evaluating your expression according to convention would give a result of 4.045084971874738 + 2.9389262614623664i, not -5 as you seem to expect.

Comment: -1. I chose the example I did because (-5)^5 = -3125. My question represents my attempt to find the 5th root of -3125. An interesting point about precision, but if we assume that it can be represented perfectly, then it definitely has at least one real answer.

Comment: +1. The only true answer. @Stargazer what you believe is "the 5th root of -3125" is only one answer between many different definitions of a root. The most general definition is exp(y log(x)), where log(x) is chosen to be the principal value Log x (note, that there are multiple choices for log(x) in the complex case). If you want a calculator that can handle these cases correctly, use [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-5%29^0.2)

Comment: @Stargazer712: If I assume that the US federal budget is balanced, then it's balanced.  That doesn't benefit anyone in any useful fashion.  The fact remains that 0.2 is not precisely representable, regardless of what assumptions you're willing to make.

Comment: If the answer is edited I'll remove my -1 (system currently won't let me). I'm withholding a +1 however, as I am not interested in answers that just say, "nope, can't do it!" I'm interested in the method, not just the answer, and in that sense, the other answers are far superior.

Answer (score 1):

Raising a negative number to a non-integral power produces a complex result.  You can use the System.Numerics.Complex class available in .NET 4 to calculate it.  For example:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;   // Add reference to System.Numerics!!

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var c = new Complex(-3125, 0);
        var p = Complex.Pow(c, 0.2);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        var result = p.Magnitude;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(4.04508497187474, 2.93892626146237)
5
```

Making the result negative is going to require some imaginative imaginary manipulations.  The value of `result.Phase` isn't large enough to warrant making it negative in any reasonable projection.