# Real cube root of a negative number

Tags: r

I'm trying to see if there is a function to directly get the real cube root of a negative number. For example, in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290804/cube-root-of-a-negative-number), there is the `Math.cbrt()` function. I'm looking for the equivalent in R.

Otherwise, my current hack is:

```
x <- -8
sign(x) * abs(x)^(1/3)
```

which is very inelegant and cumbersome to type every time. Thx!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to define your own `Math.cbrt()` function.

That will turn performing the operation from something inelegant and cumbersome to something clean, expressive, and easy to apply:

```
Math.cbrt <- function(x) {
    sign(x) * abs(x)^(1/3)
}

x <- c(-1, -8, -27, -64)

Math.cbrt(x)
# [1] -1 -2 -3 -4
```

Comment: Curious why R handles `x` differently if it is a scalar vs. a vector... My question was marked as a duplicate to this one, which doesn't answer that part... https://stackoverflow.com/q/72821589/8400969

Comment: @MichaelRoswell:  yours is an order of operations issue.  `-2^(1/3)` is the same as `-(2^(1/3))`, not `(-2)^(1/3)`.

Answer (score 3):

In R you probably need to define a new function that limits the results to your goals:

```
> realpow <- function(x,rad) if(x < 0){ - (-x)^(rad)}else{x^rad}
> realpow(-8, 1/3)
[1] -2
> realpow(8, 1/3)
[1] 2
```

It's possible to make an infix operation if you quote the operator and use surrounding "%" signs in its name. Because its precedence is low, you will need to use parentheses, but you already appear to know that.

```
> `%r^%` <- function(x, rad) realpow(x,rad)
>  -8 %r^% 1/3
[1] -2.666667    # Wrong
> -8 %r^% (1/3)
[1] -2   #Correct
```

Agree with incorporating the questioner's version for its vectorized capacity:

```
`%r^%` <- function(x, rad) sign(x)*abs(x)^(rad)
```

Comment: Good idea using the `%` shortcut. Although I think his "hack" is probably better (and it's really not a hack, you're basically just factoring out the number!). So you could do `realpow <- function(x,rad) abs(x)^(rad)*sign(x)^(1/rad)` so you don't have to do an `ifelse`

Comment: You are right, especially for the fact that your version is vectorized.

Comment: This function gives the wrong answer sometimes, e.g. if `rad = 0.5`, because `(-4)^0.5` is not -2.

Answer (score -1):

In Java something like this :

```
There are 3 cube-roots. Assuming you want the root that is real, you should do this:

x = 8;  //  Your value

if (x > 0)
    System.out.println(Math.pow(x, 1.0 / 3.0));
else
    System.out.println(-Math.pow(-x, 1.0 / 3.0));
```

Comment: He's looking for the answer in R

Comment: That link doesn't actually answer his question. Read through material before recommending it.

Comment: Well your really helping with your negative comments. At least I'm providing help in answering the question. Seems like you just can't assist in any meaningful way. And further to note, the link actually explains that it may not be possible as it results in 3 possible answers! read it before wasting your time with your discouraging disparaging comments

Comment: @topcat; I upvoted for exactly your reasoning above. It wasn't R, but it was useful information, as was your link to r-help Archives.

Comment: @DWin thank you. at least some people care to give valuable information :)