# why is this giving me an NaN

Tags: r

My problem is that I'm trying to compute  $(-1)^{1/3}$, but when I ask R to compute this an NaN occurs.

> (-1)^(1/3)

[1] NaN

I really don't know why? I'm using R 2.15.
I want to compute $(-1)^{1/3}$
in real life $(-1)^{1/3}=-1$ should be as the cubic root of -1.

Any idea??

Comment: Off-topic. Not a statistics question

Comment: Powers are computed via logarithms (a^b is *defined* as exp(b*log(a))).  For insight into this particular behavior, compare the output of `log(-1)` to `log(-1 + 0i)`.

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236158/real-cube-root-of-a-negative-number-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NaN` is produced because the largest root of `-1` is complex. You'll see the same behaviour for `(-1)^(1/2)`. This is because complex numbers are not supported in normal calculations as you would assume unless you coerce the base to be complex before.

Try

```
R> (-1+0i)^(1/3)
[1] 0.5+0.866025i
```

or

```
R> as.complex(-1)^(1/3)
[1] 0.5+0.866025i
```

You can read more about cubic roots here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html

#### Edit:

Well, my suggestions above are more workarounds than answers. I will try and explain it in more detail. Allthough it quickly gets quite hairy as you need to look at your C standard library functions.

As @whuber and @NickCox suggest in the comments there is a very good reason for the answer being `NaN`. Looking at the source code of the `^` operator you can see that this case will be calculated using the C function `double pow (double base, double exponent);` from your standard lib's `math.h`. This function has the same behaviour.

As an example you can look at this implementation: http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c Here you see that there are a few special cases listed as follows:

```
/*
 * Special cases:
 *  1.  (anything) ** 0  is 1
 *  2.  (anything) ** 1  is itself
 *  3.  (anything) ** NAN is NAN
 *  4.  NAN ** (anything except 0) is NAN
 *  5.  +-(|x| > 1) **  +INF is +INF
 *  6.  +-(|x| > 1) **  -INF is +0
 *  7.  +-(|x| < 1) **  +INF is +0
 *  8.  +-(|x| < 1) **  -INF is +INF
 *  9.  +-1         ** +-INF is NAN
 *  10. +0 ** (+anything except 0, NAN)               is +0
 *  11. -0 ** (+anything except 0, NAN, odd integer)  is +0
 *  12. +0 ** (-anything except 0, NAN)               is +INF
 *  13. -0 ** (-anything except 0, NAN, odd integer)  is +INF
 *  14. -0 ** (odd integer) = -( +0 ** (odd integer) )
 *  15. +INF ** (+anything except 0,NAN) is +INF
 *  16. +INF ** (-anything except 0,NAN) is +0
 *  17. -INF ** (anything)  = -0 ** (-anything)
 *  18. (-anything) ** (integer) is (-1)**(integer)*(+anything**integer)
 *  19. (-anything except 0 and inf) ** (non-integer) is NAN
 */
```

Where 19 corresponds to your case. In this case it gives up and returns `nan`.

```
/* (x<0)**(non-int) is NaN */
if((n|yisint)==0) return (x-x)/(x-x);
```

Ok. So what happends when we change the base to be complex?

Then we will use the function `double complex cpow (double complex x, complex double y)` from the `complex.h` library. This function can handle complex numbers and will therefore not shortcut the same way. istead computing the result as

```
double complex cpow (double complex base, double complex power)
{
  return cexp (power * clog (base)); 
}
```

Which is the same as you saw in @whuber's comment. Except this function can handle complex numbers.

Im not sure this explanation is better even though it goes into details but I hope I have answered your question one way or another.

Comment: I'm not sure you first sentence really makes sense here.  R has never been about giving "the only root".  `1^(1/4)` gives 1 even though it has 4 roots - two of which are real.

Comment: The more immediate deal is that cube rooting is not (usually) special; as @whuber underlines the usual way to do cube rooting is as a generic power, which means trying to take logarithms first internally. It's a hard expectation that (1/3) (or 1/5 or 1/7 or ...) be recognised as deserving special treatment even if code is focused only on yielding real roots.

Comment: @Dason Well, you are right. Of course i didn't mean that you get NaN just because there are several roots. I meant it is because the answer is complex. I will rephrase.