# Weird Problem in Calculating Cubic Root in R

Tags: r, cubic

If I set x=0, and then calculate:
`((x+1)/(x-1))^(1/3)`; I get NaN

But I don't get a problem if I do:

```
-1^(1/3)
```

The following two ways also cause errors:

```
((0+1)/(0-1))^(1/3)
((1)/(-1))^(1/3)
```

And, of course, the output of 
`((x+1)/(x-1))` is -1

Anyone knows what's up with R?

Comment: You're confusion is probably in thinking that for a computer, `1/3` is _exactly_ one-third, but it almost certainly is not.

Comment: Compare it to this: `((x+1)/(x-1))^1/3`. I think R takes the value and "powers it to 1" first then divides by three.

Comment: Indeed, this exact thing has been incorrectly reported to R Core as a [bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14328) in the past.

Comment: Hi Joran, interesting reading. At the end the person replying mentions " Every non-integer representable in numeric floating point is a fraction whose denominator is a power of two, so powers of negative numbers are correctly given as NaN.
A function to compute nth roots might be useful, but you shouldn't expect the power operator to do it." My follow up question is, if not the power operator, then what should we use?

Comment: Looks like the **pracma** package has an nth root function. I'd be willing to bet there are others if you do some Googling.

Comment: ...also there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13236158/324364) previous SO question.

Comment: Joran, thank, honestely. Like I always said, it looks complicated until you solve it.